# Is there a benefit to using a boolean over say, an int with an 'if' statement

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, integer, boolean

As a begineer coder, I wrote a program, something along the lines of:

```
ArbitraryVariable = 1
--Code--
--Code--
--Code--
If ArbitraryVariable == 1:
    --Code--
    --Code--
    --Code--
```

I would set ArbitraryVariable to 1 if I wanted it to do that thing, and anything else (usually 0) if I didn't, which i guess accomplishes a de facto true/false logic.

My friend who actually knows what he's doing informs me this would've been better accomplished with a boolean as it's true/false, which makes sense, but I am curious if there is actually any specific benefit to doing this, other than a very slight increase in optimisation and it seemingly just being the boolean's 'thing'?

I wrote this in python, but feel free to answer across languages.

Comment: Using a boolean would make it clear that the variable is meant to perform as a flag. It being a integer does not do that. That makes your code harder to reason about & maintain.

Comment: For one thing, it is much more user-friendly to use a boolean. In your situation, you'd need to pay close attention to close attention to realize that that variable is being used as a boolean. It just adds complexity to the reader for no reason. It might seem like a small detail, but programs get complex enough quite quickly so anything that would help with user readability is ideal (if it doesn't affect performances)

Comment: _"My friend who actually knows what he's doing informs me"_: didn't your friend also tell you why it's better? I know I would if I was telling a beginner not to do something a certain way. It's not significantly _better_ performance-wise to use a boolean instead of an integer, but it makes its usage obvious to a reader.

Comment: He sort of explained it very briefly, but I wasn't very clear on it. But he was trying to help me find errors in some existing code on his lunch time, and this came up as a side thing. Either way, thank you for helping clear up that's it is mostly for clarity / readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a great question.

Boolean is used for values that only require the true/false data types. If I'm honest it's mostly used because of coding standards that most programmers use. As you mentioned there is a slight performance increase over using an integer to denote true or false.

It also provides the positive of being easier to read and understand, you don't need operators in python if you use a boolean value. You can just do this;

```
Boolean = True

if Boolean:
  print("True")
```

and if it's false you can just use;

```
Boolean = False

if not Boolean:
  print("False")
```

Overall, the one you used should be depending on what the if statement is doing. If the question is something like Is the light on? true and false would be an appropriate answer. That's what I've found in my experience anyway.

Comment: This was a really clear and helpful answer. It seems the community concensus does not agree its a great question lol, but I found the answer really helpful. Thank you